# requests POST woes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.6

I created this Python script:

```
import requests

url = 'https://123.456.789.876:4567/config'
payload = { 'key' : '[{"aKey":"ggsdgfgdfsgsdgfdsgsgsdfgdfgf","id":"fsdfdsfdsfsdffdsfdsfsdfdfsdsfsfdsfdssf","failedOps":[],"tType":"valid","type":"mam"}]' }
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
res = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)
print(res.json)
```

When I run it I get this response:

```
<bound method Response.json of <Response [400]>>
```

If I change `print(res.json)` to `print(res.text)` I get:

```
MOCK: Could not generate configuration list from request body
```

If I remove `verify=False I get this error:

```
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='123.456.789.876', port=4567): Max retries exceeded with url: /config (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)'),))
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here. Is there an issue with the structure of my request?

Comment: The first response, at least, is a pretty obvious hint that you should use `res.json()`, not `res.json`. Depending on what sort of payload the remote host wants, you may need to use `data=json.dumps(payload)` or `json=payload` to send a JSON payload instead of form-encoded data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<bound method Response.json of <Response [400]>>`

Your response object has a `json` method, not an attribute.  See [the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).  You need to *call* it, as in:

```
print(res.json())
```

> `MOCK: Could not generate configuration list from request body`

That may be the actual content of the HTTP response (which means if you try calling the `.json()` method it's going to fail, because that's not a JSON response).

> `raise SSLError(e, request=request)
>   requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='123.456.789.876', port=4567): Max retries exceeded with url: /config (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)'),))`

That's to be expected: you're connecting to a host that is presenting a certificate for which the `requests` module does not recognize the signing authority.  There are various documents out there that describe how to add a new certificate authority to your system. The process varies by operating system and possibly by distribution.

If you want to verify SSL certificates, you generally have to use hostnames rather than ip addresses.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting the 400 response though. This works with curl. Here's what I'm sending:

`curl -k -X POST https://123.456.789.876:4567/config -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[{"aKey":"ggsdgfgdfsgsdgfdsgsgsdfgdfgf","id":"fsdfdsfdsfsdffdsfdsfsdfdfsdsfsfdsfdssf","failedOps":[],"tType":"valid","type":"mam"}]'
`

Comment: The data you're passing in your Python isn't the same as the data you're showing here in your `-d` argument.  Your Python `payload` is wrapped in an additional dictionary with a `key` element.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks for the help.